# Don't send default selected option value

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am creating a custom search form and I have this code with first option

```
<select name="something">
    <option selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="something2">
    <option selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

This is what I get in url if I select only something from second select options.

```
?s=&something=ChooseB&something2=B
```

Is it possible for form to not send this "Choose" value? Can it be done using Html or do I have to use Jquery? I am doing this in Wordpress if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
<select name="something">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="something2">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible because "choose" is also an option.
One condition is possible, first write html code and set the value of choose option empty.

```
<form  name="myform" >
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option selected  value="">Choose</option>
        <option value ="A">A</option>
         <option value ="B">B</option>
        <option value ="C">C</option>
        <option value ="D">D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and then add this javascript code ,this code return false and not submit form if select option is choose that is empty.

```
<script>
   document.myform.onsubmit = function()
   {

     var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
     var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     if((strUser)=="")
     {
       return false;
     } else { 
      return true;
     }
   }
</script>
```

**OR Simple you can do this**

```
<select name="something">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="something2">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave a space in the value. Like value=" ". This works.